# Unable to validate google recaptcha enterprise. getting error: java.io.IOException: The Application Default Credentials are not available

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, recaptcha, recaptcha-enterprise

Unable to validate google recaptcha enterprise. getting error:

```
java.io.IOException: The Application Default Credentials are not available.

java.io.IOException: The Application Default Credentials are not available. They are available if running in Google Compute Engine. Otherwise, the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a file defining the credentials.
```

I have also created credential json with service account and set in environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS and alternatively created credential json with aws external account and set in environment variable. but "I was getting required parameters" must be specified error
Note: I am able to get the token from client side but this error is from server side.

Code blocks used to get credentials:
Method1 :

```
  // If you don't specify credentials when constructing the client, the client library will
  // look for credentials via the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS.
  Storage storage = StorageOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();

  System.out.println("Buckets:");
  Page<Bucket> buckets = storage.list();
for (Bucket bucket : buckets.iterateAll()) {
    System.out.println(bucket.toString());
  }
```

Method2:

```
System.setProperty("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS", jsonPath);
System.out.println("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS");
System.out.println(System.getProperty("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"));
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(jsonPath);
  GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(fileInputStream)
        .createScoped(Lists.newArrayList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"));
  Storage storage = StorageOptions.newBuilder().setCredentials(credentials).build().getService();

  System.out.println("Buckets:");
  Page<Bucket> buckets = storage.list();
  for (Bucket bucket : buckets.iterateAll()) {
    System.out.println(bucket.toString());
  }
```

Interpreting assesment:

```
/**
      * Create an assessment to analyze the risk of an UI action.
      *
      * @param projectID: GCloud Project ID
      * @param recaptchaSiteKey: Site key obtained by registering a domain/app to use recaptcha services.
      * @param token: The token obtained from the client on passing the recaptchaSiteKey.
      * @param recaptchaAction: Action name corresponding to the token.
      */
     public static void createAssessment(String projectID, String recaptchaSiteKey, String token,
         String recaptchaAction)
         throws IOException {
       // Initialize a client that will be used to send requests. This client needs to be created only
       // once, and can be reused for multiple requests. After completing all of your requests, call
       // the `client.close()` method on the client to safely
       // clean up any remaining background resources.
       try (RecaptchaEnterpriseServiceClient client = RecaptchaEnterpriseServiceClient.create()) {

         // Specify a name for this assessment.
         String assessmentName = "assessment-name";

         // Set the properties of the event to be tracked.
         Event event = Event.newBuilder()
             .setSiteKey(recaptchaSiteKey)
             .setToken(token)
             .build();

         // Build the assessment request.
         CreateAssessmentRequest createAssessmentRequest = CreateAssessmentRequest.newBuilder()
             .setParent(ProjectName.of(projectID).toString())
             .setAssessment(Assessment.newBuilder().setEvent(event).setName(assessmentName).build())
             .build();

         Assessment response = client.createAssessment(createAssessmentRequest);

         // Check if the token is valid.
         if (!response.getTokenProperties().getValid()) {
           System.out.println("The CreateAssessment call failed because the token was: " +
              response.getTokenProperties().getInvalidReason().name());
           return;
         }

         // Check if the expected action was executed.
         if (!response.getTokenProperties().getAction().equals(recaptchaAction)) {
           System.out.println("The action attribute in your reCAPTCHA tag " +
               "does not match the action you are expecting to score");
           return;
         }

         // Get the risk score and the reason(s).
         // For more information on interpreting the assessment,
         // see: https://cloud.google.com/recaptcha-enterprise/docs/interpret-assessment
         float recaptchaScore = response.getRiskAnalysis().getScore();
         System.out.println("The reCAPTCHA score is: " + recaptchaScore);

         for (ClassificationReason reason : response.getRiskAnalysis().getReasonsList()) {
           System.out.println(reason);
         }
       }
```

Comment: An error message without details is not helpful. Also, try to format your text to make it easier to read.

Comment: Are you developing your app on an IDE? If so, please make sure that `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` is configured within the IDE.

Comment: @Dondi  am getting the value of GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS from env variable. StorageOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService(); This is the code I am using to get the credentials implicitly. I even tried to call explicitly with GoogleCredentials.fromStream(new FileInputStream(jsonPath))
        .createScoped(Lists.newArrayList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"));

Comment: Added more details in the description

Comment: I think you posted a different snippet. Originally your tag is Recaptcha Enterprise but the newer sample uses Cloud Storage. You might want to show how you initialize the Recaptcha service client instead.

Comment: @Dondi This is the code block for set google credentials and it is enterprise version only. Also RecaptchaEnterpriseServiceClient client code also mentioned. calling google credentials before this code to set credentials

Comment: Both method 1 and method 2 are the same?  Try setting the location of the JSON file to an environment variable named GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS with a complete path. The GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable must be available within the context that you call the Document AI API. Also check the method mentioned in [Passing credential using code](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#passing_code) to provide the correct path of JSON file. Refer [error messages](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/error-messages).

Comment: @JyothiKiranmayi Updated the correct code block in method2. Yes I am setting environment variable . Check the method2

Comment: Any input on this ?

Comment: Have you confirmed the path is correct and that the Java application has read access?

Comment: @Zairja Yes, Path is correct and I was able to print and see the file path

Answer (score 1):

I was able to acheive the same using recaptcha V3 instead of enterprise version. As we had to acheive scored based assesment , V3 supports score based validation.